# ManagedBean method not called from a grey box window

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf, greybox

I have problem in my project. I am using jsf1.2, towmhawk, a4j frameworks and greybox javascript. I want to get multiple username and password. so i use the below code

```
ManagedBean: psgBean
    private String username;(managedbean code)
    private String password; //setter and getters
    public String addPsgLogin()
    {
        System.out.println("inside addUP");
        if(username.length()!=0 && password.length()!=0)
        {
            psgLoginFlag=1;
            psgUserNameErrorMsg="";
            psgPasswordErrorMsg="";
        NiPsgLoginInfo psgObj=new NiPsgLoginInfo(username,password);
        userpassList.add(psgObj);

        }




My Jsp page :newInstallations

                      UserName 
<h:inputText styleClass="text_box_content" id="psgUserName"  value="#{psgBean.username}" size="35" />
<h:outputLabel id="psgUserNameErrorMsg"  styleClass="error_style" value="#{psgBean.psgUserNameErrorMsg}" />

 Password 
 <h:inputText styleClass="text_box_content" id="psgPassword"  value="#{psgBean.password}" size="35" />
  <h:outputLabel id="psgPasswordErrorMsg"  styleClass="error_style" value="#{psgBean.psgPasswordErrorMsg}" />


<h:commandButton styleClass="button_style"  value="Add" actionListener="#{psgBean.addPsgLogin}"  / >                                        

 <h:commandButton styleClass="button_style" value="Reset" onclick="psgClear()" type="button" />  

<h:outputLink   value="psgusername.faces" onclick="return GB_myShow('Solvedge smartphone Web Portal', this.href,600,850)"  >
<h:commandButton styleClass="button_style" value="View"></h:commandButton>
 </h:outputLink>
```

It has image as below [image: login page]

after adding multiple userlogins i want to see it after pressing view button. so that i have used arraylist to collect login objects and used t:datatable to list the values. and i used greybox javascript code to show a inner page

It looks like below image

[image]

You can see update button in the second page. that update button is used to update the edited values in the inputtext values. but no change occurs if i click update button. so i just called a normal backing bean method, that also not called. here is the code

other jsp page for view

```
<h:form>
<t:dataTable var="us" value="#{psgBean.userpassList}" rowIndexVar="rowid" styleClass="UserTable" id="psgLoginList" headerClass="UserTable_Header"
rowClasses="UserTable_Row1,UserTable_Row2"  columnClasses="UserTable_ColumnLeft">

<h:column>
<f:facet name="header" >
<t:outputText styleClass="table_header_value" value="S.No" /></f:facet> 
<h:inputText styleClass="text_box_content" value="#{rowid+1}" />
</h:column>                                                 

<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<t:outputText styleClass="table_header_value"
value="UserName" />
</f:facet>
<h:inputText styleClass="text_box_content"
value="#{us.username}" />
</h:column>


<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<t:outputText styleClass="table_header_value"
value="Password" />
</f:facet>
<h:inputText styleClass="text_box_content"
value="#{us.password}" />
</h:column>


<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<t:outputText styleClass="table_header_value"
value="Delete" />
</f:facet>
<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{psgBean.deletePsgLogin}">
<t:updateActionListener value="#{us}" property="#{psgBean.deletable1}"></t:updateActionListener>
<a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" reRender="psgLoginForm:psgLoginList"></a4j:support>
</h:commandButton>
</h:column>
</t:dataTable>
<h:commandButton value="Update" action="#{psgBean.saveClicking}">
    </h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="cancel" onclick="winclose()"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

here is the method in managed bean

```
public String saveClicking()
{
    System.out.println("just checking");
    return null;
}
```

this method is not called. above code is present with in form tag only. i think the problem is in with greybox code.

/

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is in the line #76 of your managed bean :-D

Comment: @ leo sorry i can't get you.how can u get my managed bean line number

Comment: If you want to get help fast, edit your code, remove ALL the unnecessary code like CSS stylings, etc. I can't even find where you call your method.

Comment: @ Mr.j4mes i deleted some unwanted style.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I put rowId(s.no) in inputbox, since it is auto incremented we cannot update the value.